# Does the A* algorithm visit every node in an undirected graph when no path to the goal node exists?

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

When no path to the goalnode exists, does the A*-Algorithm a) visit and b) expand every node in an undirected graph?
I have a monotone heuristic.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course. It will continue to search until it finds a path, and if there isn't a path then it will just continue forever \ until it reached all reachable nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for example it doesn't expand nor visit the goal node or, in general, any node that does not belong to the connected component containing the starting node.

Comment: Thanks, but every node that is connected is visited?

Comment: Every node in the same connected component of the starting node is visited.

Comment: OKay thanks that''s what I wanted to know